# "In the unlikely event"

Tags: etymology, history

You hear it in most safety demonstrations. "In the unlikely event" ... of a water landing, of an emergency evacuation, of a fire etc. etc. etc. Did this phrasing come from somewhere specifically?

Comment: Life vest talk is a required element of airlines's pre-flight safety demonstration for flights that travel over water: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-flight_safety_demonstration#Required_elements  A detailed history of the International Civil Aviation Organization, which sets the requirements, would probably tell you exactly when the possibility of water landings got added to the safety talk.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply an [*idiom*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/idiom) -- "an expression whose meaning is different from the meaning of the individual words" -- meaning "if this unlikely thing actually happens."

While [some idioms](http://all-that-is-interesting.com/post/5692281236/interesting-origins-of-7-common-english-idioms) have interesting origins, this one likely arose as a means of injecting a note of reassurance into a mention of a dire event.

Answer (score 2):

In looking at Google [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20unlikely%20event&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) and the Google book quotes that are the underlyong sources, the phrase *in the unlikely event* goes back to at least as early as 1809 discussing the "recurrence of measures calculated to diminish the profits of tillage."

A quick scan of various uses through the 19th and ealry twentieth centurt seem to refer to mostly financial, commercial and political *unlikely events*. There is a signifcant uptick in the usage in the middle and later twentieth century,  with what looks like much more usage relating to political risks.

These observations are based on written examples, and most people may now be familiar with its usage in spoken safety instructions.  While it may have become a commonplace, its meaning is fairly straightforward, and it is shorter than saying

> *We really don't think this is going to happen, and we surely do not want you to worry, but just in case . . .*